# Ember route model function called before app controller init

Tags: ember.js

I've noticed that when doing a full reload, my routes `model` function will fire prior to the application controller `init` method.

If this is by design, how can I execute code (to set up my outbound Ajax requests) prior to model being called?

Comment: In the normal flow, the model hooks are always executed before the controller is initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hooks associated with the model (`beforeModel`, `model` and `afterModel`) get called before the route's controller is instanciated.

Perhaps `beforeModel` is what you are looking for http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_beforeModel

According to the documentation, `beforeModel` is good for

> Any async operations need to occur first before the model is attempted to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ember's `initializers` in you want to load some data from the server/do some set up before application controller's `init` gets called, the code in your initializers gets executed before anything else happens in your ember app. If you are using ember-cli, there will be a folder at app/initializers where your initializer code should go.

Answer (score 0):

Refer: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/15495#issuecomment-315464778

Normally, Route model is executed before the controller. However, maintainers tell that ***there has never been a guarantee that controllers would be created in any specific order related to the route structure***.

Note: I faced this scenario of controller init called before route model when there is query parameters associated with the route URL(v3.22)